# Javafx Nested Controller

Tags: javafx-2

I have tried this nested controller stuff over and over again, but it just doesn't work for me.
I don't know why i can't get something as easy as this to work. I follow this example

```
<VBox fx:controller="com.foo.MainController">
  <fx:include fx:id="dialog" source="dialog.fxml"/>
  ...
</VBox>

public class MainController extends Controller {
  @FXML private Window dialog;
  @FXML private DialogController dialogController;

  ...
}
```

here is my code:
app.Main.fxml

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="app.MainController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
        <fx:include source="InnerFile.fxml" fx:id="innerfile"/>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

app.MainController.java

```
public class MainController {


    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private InnerFileController controller;


    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");


    }


    public void initialize() {
        controller.here(); 
    }


}
```

i'm calling a method of the nested controller '  controller.here();    ',
and get a NullPointerExecption.
I don't know what I have done wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFx Nested Controllers (FXML <include>)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543487/javafx-nested-controllers-fxml-include)

Comment: And also cross posted to [OTN](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3558242)

Answer (score 8):

The name of your variable for InnerFileController is incorrect. You have:

> @FXML private InnerFileController controller;

but should be:

> @FXML private InnerFileController innerfileController;

This is because the name of the variable for the controller of an included file is always the fx:id value with "Controller" added on to it.