# Add a custom component in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I would like to add a custom element into a VBox.

**For example**: being able to write `VBox.getChildren().add(element)` and `element` is a custom node created by me in FXML.

I already followed this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm
but the example only shows how to do this inside the same controller (a single controller, i already have my "big" controller, which is `WinnerController`, I would like to split the  two classes, one that manages the single element, and one that manages the whole scene `Winner.fxml`).

I already have a class `WinnerController` which is the controller of my FXML `Winner.fxml`.

Here the code of my `Winner.fxml`:

```
<AnchorPane id="paneWinner" fx:id="paneWinner" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1280.0" stylesheets="@winner.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="client.gui.WinnerController">

<children>
  <VBox layoutX="434.0" layoutY="125.0" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="413.0" spacing="10.0">
     <children>
        <AnchorPane id="leaderBoardElement" prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="413.0" stylesheets="@leaderBoard.css">
           <children>
              <Text layoutX="49.0" layoutY="45.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" wrappingWidth="107.13671875" />
           </children></AnchorPane>
     </children>
  </VBox>
```

I would like to dynamically add element with the id "leaderBoardElement" (so an AnchorPane + Text) into my VBox.

How can i do that?

**Edit**: I also tried with this solution:[How to understand and use `<fx:root>` , in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600926/how-to-understand-and-use-fxroot-in-javafx)
but i keep getting nothing. When i do `vbox.getChildren().add(new MyComponent());`
 called in my `WinnerController`i get nothing.

WinnerController class:

```
public class WinnerController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private VBox leaderBoard;

@FXML
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)  {
    System.out.println("Winner Init");

    MyComponent test = new MyComponent();
    System.out.println(test);


    // leaderBoard.getChildren().add(new MyComponent());
}



}
```

My Component class:

```
public class MyComponent extends AnchorPane {
@FXML
private TextField textField ;
@FXML
private Button button ;
public MyComponent() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyComponent.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.load();
        textField.setText("HELLO!");
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        // handle exception
        System.out.println("ELEMENT NOT CREATE!!!");

    }
  }
}
```

Winner.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane id="paneWinner" fx:id="paneWinner" prefHeight="800.0" 
    prefWidth="1280.0" stylesheets="@winner.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="client.gui.WinnerController">
     <children>
  <VBox fx:id="leaderBoard" layoutX="434.0" layoutY="125.0" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="413.0" spacing="10.0" />
```

MyComponent.fxml:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" fx:id="leaderBoardElement" id="leaderBoardElement">
<TextField fx:id="textField" />
<Button fx:id="button" />
```

And i call the creation and loading of `Winner.fxml` from another class like this:

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Winner.fxml"));
                if (loader!=null)
                    System.out.println("LOADER NOT NULL!!");

                try{
                    System.out.println("TRY!");

                    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
                    if(root!=null)
                        System.out.println("ROOT NOT NULL!!");

                    Scene startedGame = new Scene(root, 1280, 800, Color.WHITE);
                    if(startedGame!=null)
                        System.out.println("SCENE NOT  NULL!");

                    Stage window = (Stage) paneCarta0.getScene().getWindow();
                    if (window!=null)
                        System.out.println("WINDOW NOT NULL!!");

                    window.setScene(startedGame);
                    window.show();
                    catch (IOException Exception) {
                        System.out.println("View not found. Error while loading");

                }
```

The problem is inside the `new MyComponent()`, where probably i get an exception and it propagates to my main caller. I've tried everything but i can't figure out why it can't create the `MyComponent` object.

Comment: Is it your `leaderBoardElement` that you want controlled separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx Nested Controllers (FXML <include>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543487/javafx-nested-controllers-fxml-include)

Comment: @Zephyr Yes, i would like to add that element into my VBox when i need it. Like with javascript and append, where you can add elements into your HTML via JS. I would like to do the same thing, but i don't know how to do it in JavaFX

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543487/javafx-nested-controllers-fxml-include#12572450, or the actual Oracle tutorial on nested controllers: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers

Comment: @Zephyr i checked the answers but they don't explain how to add dynamically the custom nodes into my "bigger" FXML

Comment: The Oracle document shows how to do exactly that. Read the "Custom Components" section...

Comment: I don't get why the controller has to extend the VBox class. If i use a Anchor pane as wrapper for my content, do i have to make my controller extend the Anchor Pane class?

Comment: It doesn't. It can extend any container you wish; the VBox was just for that sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your custom component is in a separate FXML file you can do this.

In your `WinnerController` class:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getRessource("customElement.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setController(new CustomElementController()); //Or just specify the Controller in the FXML file
    myVBox.getChildren().add(fxmlLoader.load());
}
```

Edit: In this solution there should be NO `<fx:include>` tags in your main fxml

Comment: I'm doing as you suggested, but i have some problems with the CustomElementController ( or mine ). Following this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers
i added the loader of custom_control (changing the name with my fxml) in the costructor.
 But i get some problems, i think i am kind of assigning multiple times the controller to the fxml, how do i solve that?

Comment: Not sure if my edit (remove `<fx:include>`) fixed your issue. Another solution might be to define the controller in the fxml (`fx:controller="com.foo.CustomElementController"`) instead of using `setController()`.